# How can I create a Generator for TensorFlow 2 from data in multiple TFRecord files?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tfrecord

I want to create a custom generator that generates data from multiple TFRecords.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple files when specifying a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`:

`dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["record1.tfrecords", "record2.tfrecords"])`